# Sound not being output

Tags: sound, phonon

I have a USB sound bar on my machine running Kubuntu 15.04. This output works properly (using the test options on the mixer, etc). But when playing a video/Spotify/etc, nothing is output.

I disabled all other outputs and set the USB soundbar as the master output. I'm at a loss. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check that the applications themselves are not muted (I knonw this sounds stupid) or muted or set to very low levels in sound settings? You can also check with **pavucontrol** if the application is is set to use your USB sound bar, not something else. Try restarting PulseAudio by killing it with `pulseaudio -k` or replugging the USB audio device, some have had issues in the past that were solved this way.